# improve performance for postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I count the number of users in this way, it runs for 5 seconds to produce results, I am looking for a better solution

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT user_id
      FROM slot_result_primary
      WHERE session_timestamp BETWEEN 1590598800000 AND 1590685199999
      GROUP BY user_id) AS foo
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can simplify the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM slot_result_primary
WHERE session_timestamp BETWEEN 1590598800000 AND 1590685199999
```

Most importantly - make sure you have **an index on sesion_timestamp**

Comment: thanks you, I tried but the results were not better

Comment: Tried what? Putting an index on session_timestamp? How many rows are in your table?

Comment: Please post EXPLAIN ANALYZE output for your query.

Comment: I ran this command 
CREATE INDEX session_timestamp_index ON slot_result_primary (session_timestamp)
 and query again
The table has 10998516 rows

Comment: You will need to include user_id in your index to make it a bit faster

Answer (score 0):

Counting is a very heavy operation in Postgres. It should be avoided if possible. 
It is very difficult to make it better so for each row Postgress needs to go the the disc. You can indeed create a better index to choose which rows to pick from the disc faster but even with this count time will always go up in time in a linear time compared to the size of the data.

Your index should be:

```
CREATE INDEX session_timestamp_user_id_index ON slot_result_primary (session_timestamp, user_id)
```

for best results.

Still an index will not solve your count problems fully. In a similar situation I faced two days ago (with a SELECT query running 3s and count 
 running 1s) dedicated indexes allowed to push down the time of select to 0,3ms but best I could do with count was 700ms.

Here you can find a good article with a summary why count is difficult and different ways to make it better:
https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/

Comment: You should also include the query for which this suggested index is to be used.  This is the wrong index for the query suggested by @Milney above.